# Reading large PDF with BufferedReader

Tags: java, pdf, bufferedreader

I need to split a large PDF document into few smaller pieces. I have to make it executable in devices with small amount of memory, so I can't use apache pdfbox, which needs to load the entire document. How to perform this with java BufferedReader? How to resolve end of page?

Comment: What do you need to do with the smaller PDFs?

Comment: BufferedReader surely won't help you. Readers are for character based formats, but PDF is binary. You need InputStreams, not readers. But I really do not know the inners of PDF file format to help you.

Comment: Assuming by "executable" you mean "viewable in a PDF viewer": Depending on the structure of the PDF, this may be pretty complicated. E.g. every page might have all resources from the document assigned to it, not merely the ones it really uses. Can you share the PDF in question / a representative example PDF to check?

Comment: @mkl no, sorry I can't due to content of personal data , doc has around 6k pages. And yes, a customer have to be able to view splitted docs.

Comment: Where do you want to split the pdfs? On the device with only little memory? Or beforehand on some other computer with sufficient memory?

Comment: @mkl other computers with 2 gb ram. I have tried with pdfbox and it is definitely to small amount of memory. Of course device upgrade isn't a solution.

Comment: You might consider using itext using partial read modus for splitting. Depending on the kind of pdf this can reduce the required memory considerably.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Does anybody know other useful libraries?